# Need certain LINQ command using let

Tags: linq, loops, foreach, transform, let

I want to transform a foreach loop into LINQ.
The code looks like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode localNode in localXmlNodeList)
{
    var localKeyNode = localNode.SelectSingleNode(inputKeyName);
    var localValueNode = localNode.SelectSingleNode(inputValueName);

    if ((localKeyNode == null) || (localValueNode == null))
        continue;

    localReturn.Add(localKeyNode.InnerText, localValueNode.InnerText);
}
```

I wanted to use something like:

```
from X in Y
let varA = Y.A
let varB = Y.B
where method(varA, varB)
select varA, varB;
```

but I always end up using a foreach loop like:

```
foreach(var X in Y.Where(varA => something(varA.subA.microSubA, varB.subB.microSubB)))
{
    somethingAgain(varA.subA.microSubA, varB.subB.microSubB)
}
```

where I wasn't able to introduce "let".

Can Somebody help me ?

Comment: What is wrong with using foreach instead of Linq?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `let` in a `foreach` loop:

```
// Query modified slightly to make more sense...
foreach (var X in from X in Y
                  let varA = X.A
                  let varB = X.B
                  where method(varA, varB)
                  select new { varA, varB })
```

It's ugly, but it should still work - it's just an expression.

Or, better IMO, declare a separate query variable first:

```
var query = from X in Y
            let varA = X.A
            let varB = X.B
            where method(varA, varB)
            select new { varA, varB };
foreach (var X in query)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, `let` really just corresponds to another `Select` to introduce the range variable - so you can express it in dot notation as well:

```
var query = Y.Select(X => new { X, varA = X.VarA })
             .Select(p => new { p.X, p.varA, varB = p.X.VarB })
             .Where(p => method(p.varA, p.varB))
             .Select(p => new { p.varA, p.varB });
```

Answer (score 0):

Gives me the creeps...

I created a thing like:

```
foreach(var localNode in localXmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(localPseudo => new { localPseudoKeyNode = localPseudo.SelectSingleNode(inputKeyName), localPseudoValueNode = localPseudo.SelectSingleNode(inputValueName) })
    .Where(localSuperPseudo => (localSuperPseudo.localPseudoKeyNode != null) && (localSuperPseudo.localPseudoValueNode != null))
    .Select(localMegaPseudo => new { localPseudoKey = localMegaPseudo.localPseudoKeyNode.InnerText, localPseudoValue = localMegaPseudo.localPseudoValueNode.InnerText }))
{
    localReturn.Add(localNode.localPseudoKey, localNode.localPseudoValue);
}
```

instead of:

```
foreach (XmlNode localNode in localXmlNodeList)
{
    var localKeyNode = localNode.SelectSingleNode(inputKeyName);
    var localValueNode = localNode.SelectSingleNode(inputValueName);

    if ((localKeyNode == null) || (localValueNode == null))
        continue;

    localReturn.Add(localKeyNode.InnerText, localValueNode.InnerText);
}
```

Now, is LINQ really better, more readable or efficient ?

I'm not sure... or did I wrote wrong code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was meant to be at the bottom of the page. I don't come along with this.